# Selenium/Python - How to scroll by randomly choosen pixels?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm looking to generate a script in which I would ask selenium to scroll up by x pixels to be randomly choosen from a range [-15,-5].

To do so, I've done this:

---

```
random = randint(-15,-5)

if lastHeight==height:
    time.sleep(2)
    if len(users) == int_likes:
        match=True
    else:
        driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,random);")
```

---

But I've got this error:

---

```
JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: random is not defined
```

---

I'm doing something wrong or is this impossible to generate random number when scrolling with selenium?
I didn't find resources about random scroll online...

Thanks!

Comment: There, I give you a little push, now it depends to you ;), go and make good Question/Anawers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed something, it should be:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,"+random+");")
```

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly @Aldo :) Could you please give the method's name so that I could do some further researches?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, notice that random should be entered as a string:

```
import random    
random = str(randint(-15,-5))
```

Then you excecute it this way:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,"+random+");")
```